# How to force keyboard to open up for readonly IonInput?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I built a input popover for numbers, which should work like the number input for PayPal transactions. After inserting a number, the current value shifts to the left and the input number appends on the far right.

[image]

It's currently working fine in browser. But on mobile devices the keyboard will not open up, cause the `readonly` prop for the IonInput has to be set.

If I change `readonly` to `disabled` the `onKeyDown`-event will not fire.
The [keyboard Capacitor plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/keyboard#show) only provides a `show` function for Android.

Is there any way to force the virtual keyboard to open up, if the mobile device has no physical keyboard?

```js
<IonItem lines="full">
  <IonLabel>{label}</IonLabel>
  <IonInput
    autofocus readonly value={value}
    className="ion-text-right"
    inputmode="decimal" type="number"
    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
  />
</IonItem>
```

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI       : 6.6.0
   Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 6.0.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.5.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.5.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v16.13.0
   npm    : 8.1.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

## Edit 1

Tried to open the popover without `readonly` and set it via state. Firstly looking nice, keyboard shows up. But when `readonly` changes to `true` the keyboard immediately disappears again:(

## Edit 2

Tried to focus a second hidden inout without, but the events don't fire.

Comment: try `onClick={()=>YourFunction()}`. and inside `YourFunction(){Keyboard.show()}`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Will this work for IOS too? The docs show this function only for android devices.

Comment: unfortunately No, but you can use Other Cordova Keyboard Plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/keyboard

Comment: [same](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard#keyboardshow-for-android-only) beahaviour.. :/